# Using setInterval to get seek position in a song in Redux Action Creators

Tags: reactjs, redux, action, setinterval, seekbar

I build a player using React.js and Howler.js and I use Redux/Redux-Thunk to dispatch the player state and controls to the entire app.
I want to get the seek position in "realtime" to know where the seek is in the song and maybe store the value in the future. Now I'm using setInterval to dispatch an other action that get the current position every 200ms. Because it dispatch an action it updates every components connected to the store every 200ms.
Is it a good practice to use setInterval in Action Creators ?
If I have to do in the UI, so in my Player component I have to catch events like Play Pause Prev and Next track to set or kill the interval.
How do you recommand me to do this ?

My action creator :

```
export const PLAYER_INITIALIZE = 'PLAYER_INITIALIZE'
export const initialize = (trackId) => {
    return {
        type: PLAYER_INITIALIZE,
    }
}

export const PLAYER_SET_TRACK = 'PLAYER_SET_TRACK'
export const setTrack = (track) => {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {

        const { player } = getState();
        let animationId = null;
        if (player.audioObj && player.audioObj.state() != 'unloaded') {
            dispatch({
                type: PLAYER_UNLOAD,
            });
        }

        dispatch({
            type: PLAYER_SET_TRACK,
            audioObj: new Howl({
                src: API.API_STREAM_TRACK + track.id,
                html5: true,
                preload: true,
                autoplay: true,
                format: track.format,
                volume: player.volume,
                onplay: () => {
                    dispatch({
                        type: PLAYER_STARTED_PLAYBACK,
                    });
                    animationId = setInterval(() => {
                        dispatch({
                            type: PLAYER_GET_SEEK_POS,
                        });
                    }, 200);
                    dispatch({
                        type: PLAYER_STARTED_SEEK_TRACKING,
                        animationId: animationId,
                    });
                },
                onload: () => {
                    dispatch({
                        type: PLAYER_LOAD_SUCCESS,
                    });
                },
                onloaderror: (id, error) => {
                    dispatch({
                        type: PLAYER_LOAD_ERROR,
                        error: error,
                    });
                },
                onend: () => {
                    dispatch(nextTrack());
                },
            }),
            trackMetadata: track,
            duration: track.duration,
        });
    }
}

export const PLAYER_LOAD_SUCCESS = 'PLAYER_LOAD_SUCCESS'
export const loadSuccess = () => {
    return {
        type: PLAYER_LOAD_SUCCESS,
    }
}

export const PLAYER_LOAD_ERROR = 'PLAYER_LOAD_ERROR'
export const loadError = () => {
    return {
        type: PLAYER_LOAD_ERROR,
    }
}

export const PLAYER_PLAY_TRACK = 'PLAYER_PLAY_TRACK'
export const playTrack = () => {
    return {
        type: PLAYER_PLAY_TRACK,
    }
}

export const PLAYER_STARTED_PLAYBACK = 'PLAYER_STARTED_PLAYBACK'
export const startedPlayback = () => {
    return {
        type: PLAYER_STARTED_PLAYBACK,
    }
}

export const PLAYER_PAUSE_TRACK = 'PLAYER_PAUSE_TRACK'
export const pauseTrack = () => {
    return {
        type: PLAYER_PAUSE_TRACK,
    }
}

export const PLAYER_NEXT_TRACK = 'PLAYER_NEXT_TRACK'
export const nextTrack = () => {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        const { playQueue, queuePos } = getState().player;

        if (queuePos < playQueue.length - 1) {
            dispatch (setTrack(playQueue[queuePos + 1]));
            dispatch (setQueuePos(queuePos + 1));
        } else {
            dispatch (unload());
        }
    }
}

export const PLAYER_PREV_TRACK = 'PLAYER_PREV_TRACK'
export const prevTrack = () => {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        const { playQueue, queuePos } = getState().player;

        if (queuePos > 0) {
            dispatch (setTrack(playQueue[queuePos - 1]));
            dispatch (setQueuePos(queuePos - 1));
        } else {
            dispatch (unload());
        }
    }
}

export const PLAYER_SET_SEEK_POS = 'PLAYER_SET_SEEK_POS'
export const setSeek = (pos) => {
    return {
        type: PLAYER_SET_SEEK_POS,
        seekPos: pos
    }
}

export const PLAYER_GET_SEEK_POS = 'PLAYER_GET_SEEK_POS'
export const getSeekPos = () => {
    return {
        type: PLAYER_GET_SEEK_POS,
    }
}

export const PLAYER_STARTED_SEEK_TRACKING = 'PLAYER_STARTED_SEEK_TRACKING'
export const startedSeekTracking = (animationId) => {
    return {
        type: PLAYER_SET_VOLUME,
        animationId: animationId,
    }
}

export const PLAYER_SET_VOLUME = 'PLAYER_SET_VOLUME'
export const setVolume = (value) => {
    return {
        type: PLAYER_SET_VOLUME,
        volume: value
    }
}

export const PLAYER_SET_PLAY_QUEUE = 'PLAYER_SET_PLAY_QUEUE'
export const setPlayQueue = (queue) => {
    return {
        type: PLAYER_SET_PLAY_QUEUE,
        playQueue: queue || {},
    }
}

export const PLAYER_SET_QUEUE_POSITION = 'PLAYER_SET_QUEUE_POSITION'
export const setQueuePos = (pos) => {
    return {
        type: PLAYER_SET_QUEUE_POSITION,
        queuePos: pos,
    }
}

export const PLAYER_UNLOAD = 'PLAYER_UNLOAD'
export const unload = () => {
    return {
        type: PLAYER_UNLOAD,
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is it a good practice to use setInterval in Action Creators ?

No. Redux has large feedback loop and overhead. So this technique is unefficient since it triggers a lot if unnecesary operations and is not responsive enough.

In general Redux is good for state management based on "static" states. And audio playback on the other hand is a stream-like process. So my advice is to put "static info" (like song name) inside Redux. And stream-like operations should be executed directly from Howler's api.

Comment: Where do you recommand me to store my Howler object which is the sound data ?

Comment: In general I would advice create higher order component for it. But that depends on your app architecture. Definetely not inside Redux state, since it is not serializable and will break your debugging. 
If you want to do it by the book, you can create store enhancer.

Comment: Ok I understand now. But now that I moved my Howler object to the Player component how I do to call compenent function when I dispatch an action from another component ? e.g. if I want to load a new track into the player or set next button ?

Comment: Good question ;). If you want to add new song, dispatch an action. In your player subscribe to the store, and do howler actions accordingly. The concept is that the state describes what you want to do, and player component reads and tries to do that.